# Executing "Copy Dropbox Link" with a script

Tags: macos, applescript, dropbox, services, shortcut-menu

I want to create a script that executes the command from the contextual (control-click) menu, "Copy Dropbox Link". How can I access this command with Applescript (or any other Mac scripting service)?

[image: Contextual Menu with "Copy Dropbox Link" Highlighted]

My goal is to create a LaunchBar 6 (by Objective Development) action that grabs the Dropbox link of a file selected *in LaunchBar*. LaunchBar works like a high-powered version of the native Spotlight app.

I'm running OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: 1. By "Launchbar" do you actually mean **LaunchBar** as in the app from [Objective Development](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html)? 2. When you say "of a selected file", from where are you selecting the file, in Finder or where exactly? These are pieces of information you should include in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user3439894! I've clarified the issues you identified with my question.